# How can I determine if it is a bot browsing my website or a person?

Tags: java, html, jsp

How can I determine when it is a bot browsing my webpage?

I have a website where the user submits a form to get to the next page.

I do some extra background database calls so that when the user submits the form, the page is faster.

I do not need to do this when it is a bot, because they cannot access that part of the site anyway since it is accessed using a form

How can I determine when it is a bot browsing my page?

Comment: "I do some extra background database calls" how? When? When using autocompletion?

Comment: parse the USER_AGENT for bots, if it matches one, its a bot ;) but modern bots are able to submitting forms human like

Comment: HTTP header **User-Agent** and one should not forget **robots.txt**.

Comment: Sounds like optimization without having established optimization is required. don't forget every hour you spend on this is additional investment.

Comment: I don't know the code to identify but have you tried `captcha code` with images this should solve your problem

Comment: Are you interested in detecting dishonest bots, or only hinest bots?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this little trick to weed out the bots from submitting my forms... and it's been working REALLY well.

***Within the form***

```
<li class="realTest" title="We just want to make sure you're from this planet and not a robot.">
    <label class="title" for="humanTest1">Check for Human</label>
    <input type="text" name="humanTest1" id="humanTest1" tabindex="-1" placeholder="Leave this field blank. *"/>
</li>
```

***Javascript***

```
(function () {
    $('.realTest').css({'opacity' : 0, 'height' : 0, 'visibility' : 'hidden', 'position' : 'absolute', 'left' : -9999, 'z-index' : -9999});
})();
```

All you have to do is check the value. If it's empty, it's a human; if it's not, then it's a bot.